# Routing in Neo4j for OSM PointOfInterest

Tags: neo4j, openstreetmap

1.I have downloaded OSM file for one city and imported data to Neo4j via https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/osm

2.Followed README, I have added distance,Intersection, ROUTE relationship, PointOfInterest.

3.However, The ROUTE relationship is bidirectional, not sure if this is the cause of leading routing algorithm failed or not.

FYI,my script of above steps

1. Calculate distances

```
'MATCH
(awn:OSMWayNode)-[r:NEXT]-(bwn:OSMWayNode)
WHERE NOT exists(r.distance)
RETURN awn,bwn,r',
'MATCH
(awn)-[:NODE]->(a:OSMNode),
(bwn)-[:NODE]->(b:OSMNode)
SET r.distance=round(distance(a.location,b.location))',
{batchSize:10000,parallel:false});
```

2.Decide what is  intersection

```
'MATCH(n:OSMNode)
WHERE size((n)<-[:NODE]-())>2
AND NOT (n:Intersection)
RETURN n',
'MATCH
(n)<-[:NODE]-(wn:OSMWayNode),(wn)<-[:NEXT*]-(wx),
(wx)<-[:FIRST_NODE]-(w:OSMWay)-[:TAGS]->(wt:OSMTags)
WHERE exists(wt.highway)

SET n:Intersection',
{batchSize:10000,parallel:false});
```

3.Connect decision points(Intersections) with new distance relationship

```
'MATCH(x:Intersection)
CALL spatial.osm.routeIntersection(x,false,false,false)
YIELD fromNode,toNode,distance,fromRel,toRel
RETURN fromNode,toNode,distance,fromRel,toRel',
'MERGE (fromNode)-[r:ROUTE {fromRel:id(fromRel),toRel:id(toRel)}]->(toNode)
ON CREATE SET r.distance=round(distance)',
{batchSize:10000,parallel:false});
```

4.Create Point Of Interest, follow same way I created another 3 point of interest for location :{longitude:103.835553,latitude:1.3045739},{longitude:103.78152251,latitude:1.28357103},{longitude:103.8604644,latitude:1.305788741}

```
MATCH(n:OSMNode)
WHERE
distance(n.location,point({longitude:103.8958005,latitude:1.330945169})
)<100 AND (n)-[:ROUTE]->() and NOT n:PointOfInterest
WITH n,n.location as poi LIMIT 1
MATCH(m:OSMNode)
WHERE distance(poi,m.location)<100
WITH n,m
MATCH(m)<-[:NODE]-(wn:OSMWayNode),
(wn)<-[:NEXT*]-(wx),
(wx)<-[:FIRST_NODE]-(w:OSMWay)
WITH n,w
WITH n,COLLECT(w) AS ways
CALL spatial.osm.routePointOfInterest(n,ways) YIELD node
SET n:PointOfInterest,n.name="AAA"
RETURN count(node)
```

Question:

I want to use gds.alpha.spanningTree.minimum.write to get the minimum effort from Point AAA to all the others PointOfInterest, namely BBB,CCC,DDD

```
CALL gds.alpha.spanningTree.minimum.write({
  nodeProjection: 'PointOfInterest',
  relationshipProjection: {
    ROUTE: {
      type: 'ROUTE',
      properties: 'distance',
      orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'
    },
    startNodeId: id(n),
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'distance',
    writeProperty: 'MINST',
    weightWriteProperty: 'writeCost'
  }
})
YIELD createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount
RETURN createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount;
```

But I'm always having error

```
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.alpha.spanningTree.minimum.write`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct a relationship filter out of a java.lang.Long
```

Is it possible to achieve my purpose using above way?If yes, is there anything wrong with my cypher?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your error, some of [documented examples](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/minimum-weight-spanning-tree/#algorithms-minimum-weight-spanning-tree-sample) are unfortunately wrong. It looks like you were trying to follow one of the buggy examples.

The `relationshipProjection` should only contain `ROUTE`, and no other properties.

Try this:

```
CALL gds.alpha.spanningTree.minimum.write({
  nodeProjection: 'PointOfInterest',
  relationshipProjection: {
    ROUTE: {
      type: 'ROUTE',
      properties: 'distance',
      orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'
    }
  },
  startNodeId: id(n),
  relationshipWeightProperty: 'distance',
  writeProperty: 'MINST',
  weightWriteProperty: 'writeCost'
})
YIELD createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount
RETURN createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount;
```

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science/issues/59) for the documentation problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code works. But seems like there are still issue with my data model.