# Neo4j OSM Intersections and Spatial Graph Setup

Tags: neo4j, cypher, openstreetmap, spatial

I've been trying to setup Neo4j for use as a routing engine, and this has lead to two questions (amongst others).

### Main Question

When following the instructions from the [README](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/osm), after importing the OSM data, the next step is to identify intersections, as shown below:

```
MATCH (n:OSMNode)
  WHERE size((n)<-[:NODE]-(:OSMWayNode)-[:NEXT]-(:OSMWayNode)) > 2
  AND NOT (n:Intersection)
WITH n LIMIT 100
MATCH (n)<-[:NODE]-(wn:OSMWayNode), (wn)<-[:NEXT*0..100]-(wx),
      (wx)<-[:FIRST_NODE]-(w:OSMWay)-[:TAGS]->(wt:OSMTags)
  WHERE exists(wt.highway)
SET n:Intersection
RETURN count(*);
```

I haven't figured out how the `>2` works in the second line, `WHERE size((n)<-[:NODE]-(:OSMWayNode)-[:NEXT]-(:OSMWayNode)) > 2`.
Can anyone explain how this works?
I think it filters for connections to a node, where an intersection should be more than 2 connections (because it has to have multiple roads there to "intersect"). However, if there's only 2 roads at an intersection (i.e., the streets keep the same name when passing through the intersection), there seems to be only 1 connection from each street to the node, thus giving *exactly* 2 connections and failing the check. I want to believe I am missing something trivial here...

### Secondary Question

I've been combining instructions from the [README](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/osm) with the [demo](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/osm/tree/0.2-neo4j-4.2/demo) to build a routing graph. I'm certain these instructions are complete...in some fashion.
Are there more clear or updated instructions for building a routing graph in Neo4j?

### References:

- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578246/routing-in-neo4j-for-osm-pointofinterest)
- [2018 Graph Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncKreSy1oYk)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/osm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function size() returns the number of elements in a list.
> https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-size

What you mean would be the case if we only consider the following query:
`size((n)<-[:NODE]-(:OSMWayNode)) > 2`

This would only count the connected OSMWayNode and 'Street-Links' would be classified as intersections.

But because the next OSMWayNode appears in the list there can be multiple appereances for one [NODE] relation:

1. (n:OSMNode)<-[nr1:NODE]-(own1:OSMWayNode)-[wr1:NEXT]->(own2:OSMWayNode)
2. (n:OSMNode)<-[nr2:NODE]-(own3:OSMWayNode)-[wr2:NEXT]->(own4:OSMWayNode)
3. (n:OSMNode)<-[nr2:NODE]-(own3:OSMWayNode)<-[wr3:NEXT]-(own5:OSMWayNode)

(note that the [:NEXT]-relations are bidirectional in the query)

[example of an intersection in munich](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSWXY.png)

This shows two crossing roads leading to an intersection rather than a link